# Adding object with several sub-objects at once

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

Let's say I have following database:

Company (name, sector) has many Products (name, price)

I would like users of my Rails website to be able to add new companies along with their products. So the form would look like:

```
Add new company
--------------------
Name: [       ]
Sector: [       ]

Product 1:
  Name [       ]
  Price [       ]

Product 2:
  Name [       ]
  Price [       ]

Product 3:
  Name [       ]
  Price [       ]
```

Ideally users would be able to add as many products at once as required (auto expanding list?). How can I program that in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Nested Form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) - This is a Rails gem for conveniently manage multiple nested models in a single form (c)

Answer (score 0):

I tried both Nested From and [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and both are fine.  I recommend using Cocoon as it gave more control over how new items are created which I needed at the time because of single table inheritance.

In general you may want to have multiple 'Add' buttons/links for creating model views that have slightly different model attribute values. eg Add Product vs Add Service or for phone numbers, like 'add mobile/cell vs add land/fixed line'.